# java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError when changing tomcat ajp port

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

i am using **tomcat 7.0.23** in eclipse helios, and when trying to change the ports as follows:

- **Tomcat Admin Port:** 8008
- **HTTP/1.1:** 8081
- **AJP/103:** 11009

i am getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError: java/lang/Object : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

please advise how to fix it, thanks.

EDIT: forgot to mention that i have another running instance of tomcat on this machine.

Comment: Ussually this error happens when you compile your java files in a latest version and try to run it in an old java virtual machine

Comment: @Subin S, i know that, but this is has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: This is clearly because you are compiling your code in a newer version of java compared to the one running Tomcat. Version 51.0 is Java 7 and you are likely running Tomcat on top of Java 6. What does your JAVA_HOME environment variable point to?

Comment: i don't have java 7 issue was that java home points to jdk 6 update 25 and tomcat was running on jdk 6 update 20

Comment: Ok then that is exactly the problem. "Version 51.0" means that your classes are compiled for Java 7. Those classes will not work on your Java 6 installation. More info: http://java67.blogspot.dk/2012/10/how-to-fix-javalangunsupportedclassversionerror-major-minor-version-49-50-51.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after changing the **eclipse tomcat JRE** to match the one in the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Eclipse Helios with Java 7? This will not work, you will need to upgrade your Eclipse to at least [Eclipse Indigo SR1](http://eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110929_indigosr1.php)

Comment: absolutely no, i am not trying to do that.